# How to test if a value is not equal to any valid choices

Tags: c#, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to up the value of the int in the key-value pair in a dictionary using the name[key] syntax. What is passed into the function is a string of various sizes. I iterate over the string with the foreach method and continue to get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException : Value does not fall within the expected range.

The function is as follows:

```
public static IDictionary<char, int> Count(string sequence)
{
    IDictionary<char, int> Dna = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    Dna.Add('A', 0);
    Dna.Add('C', 0);
    Dna.Add('G', 0);
    Dna.Add('T', 0);

    foreach(char c in sequence)
    {
        if(c != 'A' || c != 'C' || c != 'G' || c != 'T')
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        ++Dna[c];
    }

    return Dna;             
}
```

The stack trace identifies the line where the string is passed into it and line 20 which is the ++Dna[c] line.

I am still learning C#, only a few days into it.

I have tried several of the solutions posted but get the same error. What do I need to learn more, to understand this concept?

This is from an exercise on another site.

Comment: What is value of `sequence`, passed to `Count` method? You get the error becuase throwing an `ArgumentException` exception

Comment: That code does not make a lot of sense. You have a count function. That has to create the collection it is counting on itself. And then returns the *collection*, rather then the single integer count. Is this supposed to be a "IncerementAll"? If so, why would you do it like this?

Comment: The value sequence is a random generation of letters that signify a DNA strand of various sizes (ie could be "AGTCA" or "AGGTCCAA" anything really). I seen another post that showed the property of IDictionary to be of Item[Key] where the property could be used to update the value of the key. (ie Dna['A'] = 2), so I figured ++Dna[c] would increase the <int> of the key value by one. Im not looking for the answer to solve the code, just need to know what aspects of dictionary I need to learn more about. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. It should be

```
if(c != 'A' && c != 'C' && c != 'G' && c != 'T')
{
  throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: I could not give an upvote but thank you, my logic was incorrect. It did not have anything to do with the ++Dna[c].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count only the characters, which are equal to any from `A`, `C`, `G` or `T` sequence and throw an error for characters outside this range, you should use [conditional logical AND `&&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) operator instead of [conditional logical OR `||`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) in `if` statement

```cs
foreach (var c in sequence)
{
    if (c != 'A' && c != 'C' && c != 'G' && c != 'T')
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    ++Dna[c];
}
```

Also, instead of throwing an error, you can use [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) statement to process the next iteration of `foreach` loop

```cs
if (c != 'A' && c != 'C' && c != 'G' && c != 'T')
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I think for this one I have to use the throw. Some of the strings have invalid data. But the continue I will keep in mind something I had not thought of.

Comment: I could not give an upvote but thank you, my logic was incorrect. It did not have anything to do with the ++Dna[c].